# QGIS 3.16 – Maptip shows contents only once

Tags: qgis, maptips

I'm working with QGIS version 3.16.0-Hannover on both Mac and Windows OS and I encounter the same problem with using map tip.

I added images and videos to point location by adding in the layer properties (display) the following code:

```
<span style="font-weight:bolder;font-size:18px;"> [% Target %] </span> </br>
<img src="file:///[% @project_home %]/images/[% "Photo" %]" width="290" height="180"> </img>
<video src="file:///[% @project_home %]/images/[% "Videos" %]" width="290" height="180" type="video/mp4" controls/> </video>
```

Then, when I hover over the points with the map tip activated I can correctly see images and videos in the pop-up. However, the pop-up only appear one time and to see its contentsagain I have to close and reopen QGIS.

I'm sure there is something wrong in the code or in the properties of the file. Can anyone relate to this issue and know how to resolve it?